# Translating form validation messages

Tags: symfony, twig, translation

I'm trying to translate validation messages of login form but probably I'm doing something wrong. 
Here's what I did so far.

`NS/AppBundle/Resources/translations/validations.br.yml` and the content of that file is

```
Bad credentials.:translated message
```

Then in the twig file

```
<div class="error">{{ error.message|trans({},'messages') }}</div
```

The project also has a file `NS/AppBundle/Resources/translations/messages.br.yml`
Everything from that file is translated as expected.

Already tried with clear cache.

So what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you set a default locale and the user's locale?

Comment: Yes I did. All translations except the validation works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to utilize a translation file in the `validations` domain, why are you using a `trans` filter with the `messages` domain? Twig should be:

```
<div class="error">{{ error.message|trans({},'validations') }}</div>
```

See [this link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translations-in-templates) on the translation domains and how they're utilized in the Twig templating, and [this section in the same link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations) on the naming convention of translation files and how they relate to the translation domains.